# Can't set enp1s0 interface in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp

I want to set my primary ethernet adapter to static ip because DHCP makes problem every time in my connections.

here's my /etc/network/interfaces.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.40
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

And I do restart networking by `services networking restart`
and error appears.

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since sun 2017-02-26 02:05:44 KST; 20s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 13609 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo (code=exite
  Process: 13637 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FA
  Process: 13629 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n 
 Main PID: 13637 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 2월 26 02:05:44 haseunggabserver systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
 2월 26 02:05:44 haseunggabserver ifup[13637]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
 2월 26 02:05:44 haseunggabserver ifup[13637]: Failed to bring up enp1s0.
 2월 26 02:05:44 haseunggabserver systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited,
 2월 26 02:05:44 haseunggabserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces
 2월 26 02:05:44 haseunggabserver systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed 
 2월 26 02:05:44 haseunggabserver systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. '
```

But when I try this : just add `#` before `auto enp1s0`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    #auto enp1s0
    iface enp1s0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.40
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

`networking` restarts successfully.

I think nothing wrong in my interfaces file.. but I don't know why this appears.

my ifconfig :

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:8d:5c:d7:a7:0a  
          inet addr:192.168.0.40  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8c37:9a69:f4f6:dd92/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:135599 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:135766 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14013385 (14.0 MB)  TX bytes:139304076 (139.3 MB)

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:8d:5c:d7:a7:09  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:95769 (95.7 KB)  TX bytes:95769 (95.7 KB)
```

Any ideas to fix this?
regards.